# How to overlap a picklist field dropdown over a lightning card in LWC?

Tags: javascript, html, css, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I have tried inserting the below css,

```
.table-responsive,
.dataTables_scrollBody {
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```

But still it does not work.

When i use a dropdown picklist field over a modal, the below css helps, but not in lightning card

```
.slds-modal__content{
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to notice here, like Model is **Positioned Element** but lightning-card is not.

So you cant expect the exact behavior of Model from lightning-card. But with some CSS changes, we can achieve it.

1]
If your dropdown is an immediate child of lightning-card you can add following element as the last immediate child of lightning-card.

```
<div class="slds-scrollable" style="height:30rem">
```

2]
You can add a custom class to the lightning card and apply the following CSS.

```
.custom-class{
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
```